# Exclude arrowheads in legend entry on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm drawing a `geom_path()` and I'd like it to have arrows in the plot, but not have arrows in the legend. Googling around suggests that something of the form

```
guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(..))
```

will have the answer, but I can't find documentation of what that `list()` expects.  The help file for `guide_legend()` says to "look at the examples" to learn more about `override.aes` but there is only one example showing how to set the alpha level in the legend.

To make what I'd like to do concrete, here's code that produces a plot with arrowheads,

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 1, 2),
                   y=c(1, 2, 1, 1),
                   color=c('color1', 'color1', 'color2', 'color2'))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color, group=color)) +
  geom_path(size=2,
            arrow = arrow(angle = 30, 
                          length = unit(0.1, "inches"),
                          ends = "last", type = "closed")) +
  theme_bw()
```

This outputs
[image: Plot with arrowheads]

But what I'm looking for is the legend with the not arrowhead version, as in

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color, group=color)) +
  geom_path(size=2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, this should work:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color, group=color)) +
  geom_path(size=2,
            arrow = arrow(angle = 30, 
                          length = unit(0.1, "inches"),
                          ends = "last", type = "open")) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(arrow = NULL)))
```

However, it doesn't.

The alternative is to give `GeomPath` a new legend-drawing function that doesn't draw an arrow:

```
# legend drawing function that ignores arrow setting
# modified from ggplot2 function `draw_key_path`,
# available here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/884fdcbaefd60456978f19dd2727ab698a07df5e/R/legend-draw.r#L108
draw_key_line <- function(data, params, size) {
  data$linetype[is.na(data$linetype)] <- 0

  grid::segmentsGrob(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha),
      lwd = data$size * .pt,
      lty = data$linetype,
      lineend = "butt"
    )
  )
}

# override legend drawing function for GeomPath
GeomPath$draw_key <- draw_key_line

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color, group=color)) +
  geom_path(size=2,
            arrow = arrow(angle = 30, 
                          length = unit(0.1, "inches"),
                          ends = "last", type = "closed")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that this changes `GeomPath` for the remainder of your R session. To revert back to the original behavior, you can set:

```
GeomPath$draw_key <- draw_key_path
```

Answer (score 11):

One slightly hacky way to do this is simply to use the legend created by `geom_line` rather than the arrowhead one. Here I call `geom_path` with `show.legend = FALSE` to hide the arrowhead legend. Then I use `geom_line`, which just plots lines on top of the existing lines (so the plot doesn't change) but gives us a legend without arrowheads.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data = tibble(x=c(1, 1, 1, 2),
                  y=c(1, 2, 1, 1),
                  color=c('color1', 'color1', 'color2', 'color2'))

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color, group=color)) +
  geom_path(
    size=2,
    arrow = arrow(
      angle = 30,
      length = unit(0.1, "inches"),
      ends = "last", type = "closed"
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea!  Because of reasons it can't be a geom_line in my real application...but maybe I can do geom_line with 0 alpha on the plot and then use override to make the geom_line show up for the legend.  Thanks!

Comment: That did in fact work.  +1 for a clever solution.  I'm going to wait a little longer to see if anyone suggests something less hacky, but if nothing shows up I'll come back and accept.  Thanks again.

Comment: It does indeed not seem possible to switch off the arrow. However, it is possible to provide `GeomPath` with a new legend-drawing function that doesn't draw arrows. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594001/4975218).